# Phone slope Android

Tags: android

I want to write game for Android and I need to use inside AI phone slope in some way ( in degree or any other measure). Can anybody tell me how to do that(link or code sample) ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to use phone's movement sensors (ie. accelerator, orientation)? 
APIDemos from Android SDK are always a good start:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html

Code example on how to use phone's sensor:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/os/Sensors.html

Comment: close the question if it's already solve your problem, thanks